# how to give my class permission to create files or to only read files from certain dir?

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

I am creating a class that creats for other objects some temporary directories so that they could creat tmp files in it ... or read some files from it.
This class should create 2 dirs working_dir and recource_dir.
any object has the right to create files into working_dir but it's allowed only to read files from recource_dir.
Could any one give me some ideas or to suppot me with some libs that does this.
I like using boost.

for example ... if we have object OB then we call OB.CreateFile("path-to-recource-dir") then an error should be thrown that objects can not create files in this dir.
Like when someone is not allowed to create files in root dir without permission.

thanks

ps: using Linux

Comment: Sounds like you need your own custom file stream and if it is pointing to the resource directory it only supports read operations and does read and write on the working directory.

Comment: There is no way to enforce such granularity. Unless you make your own classes for reading and writing files, and *only* use them. However anyone using your code could easily bypass that and use standard file functions instead.

Comment: for example ... if we have object OB
then we call OB.CreateFile("path-to-recource-dir")
then an error should be thrown that objects can not create files in this dir.